# How to get name of object's action/animation in python script for BGE?

Tags: python, blender

Is someone knows how to get name of object's action? For example I have a Cube with some animation CubeAction. How get this name ("CubeAction") in python script for blender game engine usage with playAction(..) method?

**CubeAction:**
[image]

Comment: Have a look at [blender.stackexchange](https://blender.stackexchange.com) for blender specific help.

Answer (score 5):

While using blender, an object can have one action assigned to it, this can be found in `object.animation_data.action`.

```
obj = bpy.context.object
print(obj.animation_data.action.name)
```

A complete list of actions can also be found in `bpy.data.actions`

```
for a in bpy.data.actions:
    print(a.name)
```

You can look at the actions [`id_root`](https://docs.blender.org/api/2.79b/bpy.types.Action.html#bpy.types.Action.id_root) to determine what type of objects the action supports, generally that would be `OBJECT` or `ARMATURE`.

While the game engine is running, there is no active action for an object, it needs to be started through an [action actuator](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/game_engine/logic/actuators/types/action.html) or [`playAction()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/2.79b/bge.types.KX_GameObject.html#bge.types.KX_GameObject.playAction). I don't know if you can get a list of actions while the game is running but without being able to create new ones, you can store the list of available actions in a script while creating the game.

Comment: and which object has which action ?

Comment: @Phil you have to go from object to action to find the relationship, with blenders sharing of data blocks the same action data can be assigned to multiple objects so the action doesn't know what object it is attached to. While not all actions have data that is useful on all objects, you can assign them to any object.